# string list members in sample string in Python

Tags: python, string, list, iteration

I have a list of strings that I want to check aren't in a non-list string.  E.g., say I have

```
myString = 'zyxwvutsr'
```

and

```
l = ['abc', 'def']
```

I want to iterate over the members of `l` and check that these aren't substrings of `myString`, and only exit a checking loop when both `abc` and `def` are found in the source string.

It feels like I should be able to write something like

```
while s for s in l not in myString:
    myString += random character
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will add random letters to a string until the strings contained within `l` are inside your string.

It uses [`string.ascii_lowercase`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase) to get the letters `a-z` and [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/random.html#random.choice) to pick a random character from this string for adding to `s`.

The `while` loop uses [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#all) to check that all of the sub-strings contained within `l` are inside `s`.

```
import random
import string

lower = string.ascii_lowercase # letters a-z

s = 'zyxwvutsr'

l = ['abc', 'def']

# This loop will continue while the string s does not
# contain all of the substrings in l
while not all(i in s for i in l):
    s += random.choice(lower)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
myString = 'zyxwvutsr'

l = ['abc', 'def', 'wvu']


for word in l:
    if word in myString:
       print(word)
```